# return custom errors from angular directives

Tags: angular

From what I have learnt so far, validation errors are written in html but how to do return custom errors. For instance I have this below directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[verifySalaryUp]', // Attribute selector
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => VerifySalaryUpDirective), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class VerifySalaryUpDirective implements Validator {

  @Input('status') status: any;
  @Input('oldSal') oldSalary;

  constructor() {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    let newSalary = control.value;
    if (this.status === 'N') {
      return null;
    } else {
      if (Number(newSalary) < Number(this.oldSalary)) {
        return {
          lowSalary: {
            valid: false
          }
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The html part is as follows

```
<span *ngIf="salVar.errors.lowSalary">Salary entered cannot be lesser than the previously entered salary.</span>
```

But What I would like is to return in the html is that the salary entered cannot be lesser than (numeric value) since that value can be obtained from the directive

Comment: why downvoting? Do you have a link to share where you have the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned error can contain any data you want.

So if you return

```
 return {
      lowSalary: {
        valid: false,
        oldSalary: Number(this.oldSalary)
      }
    }
```

you can use it in your template like that

```
<span *ngIf="salVar.errors.lowSalary">
    Salary entered cannot be lesser than {{salVar.errors.lowSalary.oldSalary}}.
 </span>
```